# mcrypt example not working

Tags: c++, ubuntu, mcrypt

I am working on ubuntu in c++ code. I wanted to test an exmple with mcrypt from this link: http://linux.die.net/man/3/mcrypt , but whn i do:

```
gcc test.c -o testt -lmcrypt
```

there is no result back. why?

Where am I wrong?

For both examples the result is the same. appreciate!!

Comment: when i run ./testt there is no result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
gcc test.c -o testt -lmcrypt
```

gives no result, because there is no error (see UNIX culture[1]).

Try to run the resulting binary with

```
./testt
```

to see the output (if any).

Probe the file, if you will

```
file ./testt
ldd ./testt
objdump -Ct ./testt
```

If all is well, you'll get all kinds of information about your file :)

---

[1]: in The Art Of Unix Programming: http://www.faqs.org/docs/artu/ch01s06.html